# Sobolev spaces types and cotypes

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces

Given $1\le p < \infty$, I am aware that $L^p$ is of type $\min\{2,p\}$ and of cotype $\max\{2,p\}$. It seems reasonable to assume that the Sobolev space $W^{k,p}$ ($k$ times weakly differentiable, $L^p$-integrability) is thus also of type $\min\{2,p\}$ and cotype $\max\{2,p\}$, yet I have not been able to find a reference for that.

Also, I am not quite sure if there are multiple kinds of types (Rademacher type, Fourier type,...?), and what their relationship is. So just to be sure, here is the definition of type I need.

Let $1\le p\le\infty$ and let $Z_j$ be a sequence of Bernoulli-Rademacher random variables. A Banach space $E$ is said to be of type $p$ if there is a type constant $C>0$ such that for all finite sequences $(x_n)_{n=1}^N$ in $E$, $$\left\|\sum_{n=1}^N Z_n x_n\right\| \le C\left(\sum_{n=1}^N \|x_n\|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

The question is then what the type of $W^{k,p}$ is. I would be very glad if someone could point me to a reference where this question is treated, or provide a proof themselves. If this is relevant, you may assume that $W^{k,p} = W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ for some very nice set $\Omega$, say the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^d$. You may also assume $k=1$.

Comment: There are several notions of type and cotype: Rademacher type/cotype, stable type/cotype etc.

Comment: I though so, this is why I included the definition. More precisely, the definition can be found in Ledoux, M., Talagrand, M.: Probability in Banach spaces, page 246.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Pelczynski and Senator (http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/sm/sm84/sm84113.pdf ) the answer is that the Sobolev spaces have the same type and cotype as the parent $L^p$ space provided that the domain you're looking at is sufficiently nice.  The unit ball in $\mathbb R^2$ would fall into the category of "sufficiently nice".

Wojtaszczyk provides a proof for the case of $W^{1,p}(\mathbb T^2)$ in his book *Banach spaces for analysts*, and Albiac and Kalton (*Topics in Banach space theory*) hint at it as well in section 6.2 without outright saying so.

There doesn't seem to be (that I can find, or think of) a simple proof of this fact though.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an "indirect" and partial result: $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$, where $\infty>p\ge 2$ and $k\in\mathbb{Z}_+$ and $\Omega$ could be open sets $\mathbb{R}^d$ and torus, has type 2.

To see this, firstly notice that we have $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ has martingale type 2, which is shown, for example, in

BRZEZNIAK 1995 https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01048965.

Then, since $W^{k,p}(\Omega)$ is UMD, and for UMD spaces, the notion of martingale type $p$ and type  $p$ are equivalent, which is shown in

Analysis in Banach spaces Vol I, https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-48520-1

then we arrive at this result.